# To extend time out during js report generation in asp.net core

Tags: jsreport

I have a rather complicated html code in the view and the report needs a longer time than the default 30 seconds to generate the structure. I'm using JSReport version 2.7.1. Initially, I tried modifying the jsreport.config.json file from "chrome": { "timeout": 180000 } to a very big number but that did not work.

And so ,I have been trying to extend jsreport timeout and here is where I am at.

```
 HttpContext.JsReportFeature()
            .Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
            .Configure((r) => r.Template.Chrome = new Chrome
            {
                Landscape = true,
                Format = "Legal",
                HeaderTemplate = header,
                FooterTemplate = footer,
                DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
                MarginTop = "95px",
                MarginLeft = "20px",
                MarginRight = "20px",
                MarginBottom = "40px"
            }
            )
            .Configure((r) => r.Options = new jsreport.Types.RenderOptions
             {
                 Timeout = 600000
             });
```

In the above case the styling works but the timeout is not implemented. However if i reverse the order of the configure and put the timeout first and the styling next, the timeout works but not the styling.

I have also tried the below method and even here it's either a case of report loading without the style or timing out with the error "JsReportBinaryException: Error rendering report: starting rendering process..rendering has finished with errors:A critical error occurred while trying to execute the render command (2). Timeout Error: pdf generation not completed after 30000ms (1). caused by error (2):-> stackError: at onCriticalError (D:\snapshot\jsreport\node_modules\jsreport-cli\lib\commands\render.js:302:19) at D:\snapshot\jsreport\node_modules\jsreport-cli\lib\commands\render.js:298:12caused by error (1):-> meta = {"workerTimeout":true,"logged":true}-> stackError: at Timeout. (D:\snapshot\jsreport\node_modules\jsreport-chrome-pdf\lib\conversion.js:293:19) at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17) at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)"

```
 HttpContext.JsReportFeature()
 .Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
 .Configure(cfg =>
 {
     cfg.Options = new RenderOptions
     {
         Timeout = 600000
      };
      cfg.Template.Chrome = new Chrome
      {
                     Landscape = true,
                     Format = "Legal",
                     HeaderTemplate = header,
                     FooterTemplate = footer,
                     DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
                     MarginTop = "95px",
                     MarginLeft = "20px",
                     MarginRight = "20px",
                     MarginBottom = "40px",
                     PrintBackground = true
      };                     
      })
```

Is there a way I can combine both and have both working?

Comment: I believe you set it in config file.

Comment: @sairfan I tried changing it in  jsreport.config.json file but that did not fix the issue. The timeout change did not happen and i get the same error.

Comment: you working with asp.net core right? this config was used for a asp.net web app `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2000000" />`

Answer (score 1):

as you said your html is rather complicated you can set templatingEngines.timeout and extensions.scripts.timeout in jsreport.config.json

https://jsreport.net/blog/long-reports#timeouts-for-pdf-rendering